# Evaluate maths operators from string to use with random number

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, eval

I have a maths quiz, where the numbers are randomized and so are the operators but to make the operators random I had to put them in a string and use Math.random which all works however when trying to calculate the questions I am unsure how to evaluate the maths operators.

```
var operationArray = ['x','&#247','+','-'];
var randomOperation1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*operationArray.length);
var randomOperation2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*operationArray.length);


  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 5;
  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 10;
  var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
  _questionText = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = randomNumber1 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation1] + " " + randomNumber2 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation2] + " " + randomNumber3;

_decimalAnswer = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
  _answer = Math.round(_decimalAnswer);
```

After researching I came across eval() but failed to see how this would work when the numbers have random values and the operators are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allthough i would not recommend using eval ( evil ) at all. This might be necessary in this case.

```
var operationArray = ['x','&#247','+','-'];
var randomOperation1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*operationArray.length);
var randomOperation2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*operationArray.length);

var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 5;
var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 10;
var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
_questionText = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = randomNumber1 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation1] + " " + randomNumber2 + " " + operationArray[randomOperation2] + " " + randomNumber3;
```

Replace the operators with the actual operators used by the code

```
_questionText = _questionText.replace(/&#247/g, '/').replace(/x/g, '*');
```

Evaluate the string.

```
_decimalAnswer = eval(_questionText);
_answer = Math.round(_decimalAnswer);
```

Comment: Good idea and I don't see why it wouldn't work, but it's not. I will post an update once I find out why. Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work ? I tested the code in the Chrome Console and it worked for me.

Comment: There was an error in my code, nothing to do with what you shared. Your approach works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correct, generally you want to achieve this:

```
var data = [1, "+", 2];
var result = yourFunction(data);
console.log(result);//3
```

To do it, you need write parser, which will work with your array, and perform actions. Something like this:

```
var result = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  switch(data[i]){
    case '+':
      result += data[i + 1];
      i++;
      break;
    default:
      result = data[i];
  }
}
```

If you need more complex solution, please see [this shitcode](http://www.html.by/threads/39822-degradacionnaja-matematika)